# Hand off control between java threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two threads; let's call them the main thread and the child thread.

The child thread runs user-submitted code that is instrumented to call a `yield` callback I provide, every time a certain condition is hit.

The child thread has a wrapper object that starts it and provides a method `handOff`, which is called from the main thread. `handOff` should pause the execution of the main thread and unpause the execution of the child thread. When the `yield` callback is called from the child thread, the child thread should pause, and the main thread should unpause.

The wrapper object also has a `killChild` method. The next time `handOff` is called after `killChild` is called, the child thread should stop execution.

So, the flow of control looks something like this:

```
Main:  startChild-->handOff........-->handOff........-->killChild-->handOff-->
Child:                     -->yield..........-->yield...............
```

Where `-->` represents arbitrary code running and `...` represents a paused thread.

It's essentially a single-threaded program, I just need to be able to force user-submitted algorithms to be reentrant. Yes, it's fairly horrible.

What would be a good way to implement this?

Comment: You could use `Object.wait()` and `Object.notify()`, but I couldn't tell you exactly how, without looking at your source. Also if you don't plan on concurrency, then why use threads to begin with? There is overhead involved in threads (creation, context switching, et al).

Comment: I need to be able to pause user code - that is, user-submitted class files I load and call into at runtime with reflection - in the middle of execution, and then resume it later. Java doesn't have anything like coroutines built-in (anymore), so I'm hacking it with threads. I'm also pushing to change requirements so that user code has to be reentrant, but in the meantime I'm making do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to implement this is just to not use threads in the first place. You can still separate the code in different methods and classes.

Assuming you need to use threads for some reason then this can be done with a simple `Object lock = new Object()` along with `wait` and `notifyAll`.

The threads take turns waiting on the lock object, then when they want to yield/handoff they `notifyAll` then `wait`. The kill is just a flag to be set in the object, when you return from the `wait` check the flag and exit if it is set.